# Plotting multiple sets of data in libreoffice calc

Tags: libreoffice

I've a question about libreoffice calc. In this [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApTnKRBS-LRfdE9uS1Z3V3c4cHk1blVJcUJ4VlM1aHc&usp=sharing) I have multiple sets of data. I want to plot mass vs volume for each one. I need to plot them all on the same chart/graph.

I'd appreciate any help or input you guys have to offer.

Comment: Did my answer below fix your problem?

Comment: @Mahiro Can you please include a screenshot of the googlesheet. Link is not active now. This will be beneficial for anyone else referring this question.

Answer (score 5):

You can do that easily. This is not an ubuntu question though, I think.

Anyway, in libre-office calc go to "Insert - Chart".

After creating a chart (XY (scatter) probably), right click on it and click on "Data ranges". A menu will pop out. Go to the tab "Data series", and add as many data series as you want. Each data series consists of a graph. Looking at your link, you'll probably want 3 data series, 1 for each solution! The lines will have different colors, and you should edit their legend for easier comprehension.